# Handling multiple datastores within a single transaction with Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-transactions

We inherited a service that was performing poorly (using elasticsearch as its datastore) and we were asked to implement a connection to a database to help speed up some issues - specifically with aggregations.

We have the code in place and it is working, however I wanted to reach out to the SO community and ask about Transactions.  How do we handle transactions now that we're writing to both ES and MySQL?  How do we handle rollbacks?

I've searched around, but havent been able to find anything useful.  Does anyone here have any recommendations or places to point me towards?

Thanks!